# Trouble Mounting Azure File Share in Kubernetes with UAMI: "Failed to Get Account Name from CSI" Error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-managed-identity, fileshare, csi-driver

I'm facing an issue with mounting an Azure File Share in a Kubernetes cluster using User-Assigned Managed Identity (*UAMI*). Although I already have the Azure File CSI driver installed and it is running correctly, I keep encountering the error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                From               Message
  ----     ------       ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    45s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mypod to aks-agentpool-xxxx
  Warning  FailedMount  14s (x7 over 46s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azure" : rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = failed to get account name from csi-xxx
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Verified UAMI Permissions:UAMI has “Storage Account Contributor" role on the Azure storage account.
2. Checked AzureIdentity and AzureIdentityBinding in Kubernetes: Ensured that these resources are correctly configured. The AzureIdentity has the correct `clientID` and `resourceID`, and the `AzureIdentityBinding`’s selector matches the `aadpodidbinding` label in my pod.
3. Pod Configuration: My pod has the correct aadpodidbinding label. The pod.yaml is configured to use SMB protocol
4. CSI Driver Logs: I am unable to retrieve logs from the Azure File CSI driver pods. Running `kubectl logs -l app=csi-azurefile -n kube-system` returns "`No resources found in kube-system namespace,"` even though the pods are present and running.
5. Pod Events: Reviewed events for the pod but didn't find specific clues pointing to the root cause of the issue.

I think the issue might be related to UAMI authentication or Azure File CSI driver configuration but am unable to pinpoint the exact cause. The fact that I can't access the CSI driver logs is also puzzling.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this or further diagnose the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To mount an Azure File Share on a Kubernetes cluster using a User-Assigned Managed Identity, you should start by creating an AKS cluster with [user assigned managed identity.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity)

This can be achieved using the following Azure CLI command-

```
az aks create -g <YourResourceGroup> -n <YourManagedClusterName> --enable-managed-identity
```

[image]

You can verify the same using
az identity show --ids 
[image]

or from portal
[image]

**Next comes the Azure file share mounting part.**

Go to your cluster, determine your cluster's resource group name by using the [`az aks show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks#az-aks-show) command with the `--query nodeResourceGroup` parameter.

```
az aks show --resource-group YourResourceGroup --name YourManagedAKSClusterName --query nodeResourceGroup -o tsv
```

*Output*:
[image]

Next, create a storage account :

```
az storage account create -n <YourAKSStorageAccountName> -g <YournodeResourceGroupName> -l <yourchoiceOflocation> --sku Standard_LRS
```

[image]
Following this, declare the storage account connection string as an environment variable for future use in file share creation:

```
export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=$(az storage account show-connection-string -n storageAccountName -g resourceGroupName -o tsv)
```

Proceed to create the file share, replacing `shareName` with your chosen name:

```
az storage share create -n shareName --connection-string $AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
```

*Output*
[image]
[image]

Export the storage account key:

```
STORAGE_KEY=$(az storage account keys list --resource-group nodeResourceGroupName --account-name <youraksstorageaccountname> --query "[0].value" -o tsv)
```

Use these credentials to create a Kubernetes secret. you will need these values when creating the Kubernetes volume.
`kubectl create secret`

output
[image]

Mount file share as a persistent volume, the default value for `fileMode` and `dirMode` is *0777*.

Next, setup the persistent volume and claim by applying the configuration accordingly.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: file.csi.azure.com
  name: azurefile
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: azurefile-csi
  csi:
    driver: file.csi.azure.com
    volumeHandle: unique-volumeid  # make sure this volumeid is unique for every identical share in the cluster
    volumeAttributes:
      resourceGroup: resourceGroupName  # optional, only set this when storage account is not in the same resource group as node
      shareName: aksshare
    nodeStageSecretRef:
      name: azure-secret
      namespace: default
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0777
    - file_mode=0777
    - uid=0
    - gid=0
    - mfsymlinks
    - cache=strict
    - nosharesock
    - nobrl
```

```
kubectl create -f azurefiles-pv.yaml
```

[image]

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azurefile
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile-csi
  volumeName: azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

```
kubectl apply -f azurefiles-mount-options-pvc.yaml
```

[image]

Confirm the creation and binding of the PVC:

```
kubectl get pvc azurefile
```

output

[image]

Update your container specifications to integrate the PVC.

[image]
[image]

Reference Document:
[Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity)
[Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-files-storage-provision)
[Mount File share guide](https://medium.com/@intruder2021/how-to-mount-folder-from-azure-files-to-a-deployment-in-aks-6de90d11aced)
[Similar thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/560362/aks-file-share-persistent-mounting-with-managed-id)